How to avoid ghost values being recorded while using textfields in UITableView
quantityTextfields are getting ghost values (values that are not putted by user in text field) Even when only one text field is changed, I think this is because how TableView Cells are reused, but how to resolve it
Below is the declaration of quantityTextFields
  private var quantityTextFields: [Int:[String: UITextField]] = [:] // Map material codes to text fields




extension CompetitorSaleThruVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    selectedMaterials.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
   let cell = tblView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "competitorCell", for: indexPath) as! CompetitorCell
    
    let material = selectedMaterials[indexPath.row]
    
    cell.quantityTextField.text = ""
   
    cell.label.text = material.value
    
    //quantityTextFields[material.value] = cell.quantityTextField
    
 
    quantityTextFields[indexPath.row] = [material.value:cell.quantityTextField]
  

    
   // cell.quantityTextField.text = textFieldValues[indexPath.row]
    cell.quantityTextField.tag = indexPath.row
    
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    
    cell.quantityTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    
    cell.quantityTextField.delegate = self
    
    return cell
    
    if navigatedFromCompetitorDisplayCell == true && material.value == competitorMaterial {
        cell.quantityTextField.text = String(compSaleQuantity)
    }
    
    
    
    
}
}


Instead of setting a static identifier like "competitorCell" above, add a dynamic identifier to each cell. Add If condition to check "dequeueReusableCell" function return nil, if yes manually create cell and assign dynamic identifier.
Note: Assigning dynamic identifier is not good practice.

Cells are reused ... trying to track a UI element (such as a text field) in a cell and handling its changes the way you are doing it is going to be prone to errors and "mis-matches."
A much better approach is to handle the text field editing in your cell class, and then use a "callback" closure to let the controller know the field has been edited.
So, we add a closure like this to the cell class:
class CompetitorCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    // "callback" closure
    var quantityEdited: ((CompetitorCell, Int) -> ())?

In the cell class, we add the target and handle editing:
// in cell init
{
    // action when field is edited
    quantityTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(edited(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
}   

@objc func edited(_ sender: UITextField) {
    let str = sender.text ?? ""
    // execute the "callback" closure
    self.quantityEdited?(self, Int(str) ?? 0)
}

Then, in your controller in cellForRowAt:
    // set the "callback" closure
    cell.quantityEdited = { [weak self] theCell, theValue in
        
        // safely unwrap optionals
        guard let self = self else { return }
        guard let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: theCell) else { return }
        
        // update our data
        self.materials[indexPath.row].quantity = theValue
        
    }

Here is a complete example - no @IBOutlet or @IBAction connections... just assign a blank view controller's custom class to CompTableVC

Simple Data Struct
struct Material {
    var name: String = ""
    var quantity: Int = 0
}


Cell Class - with label and text field
class CompetitorCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    // "callback" closure
    var quantityEdited: ((CompetitorCell, Int) -> ())?
    
    static let identifier: String = "CompetitorCell"
    
    let label = UILabel()
    let quantityTextField = UITextField()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        quantityTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        contentView.addSubview(quantityTextField)
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 42.0),

            quantityTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            
            quantityTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            quantityTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            quantityTextField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
        ])
        
        quantityTextField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        quantityTextField.keyboardType = .numberPad
        
        // action when field is edited
        quantityTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(edited(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
        
        // so we can see the framing
        label.backgroundColor = .cyan
        quantityTextField.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
    }
    
    @objc func edited(_ sender: UITextField) {
        let str = sender.text ?? ""
        // execute the "callback" closure
        self.quantityEdited?(self, Int(str) ?? 0)
    }
}


Sample Controller Class
class CompTableVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    var materials: [Material] = []
    
    let tableView = UITableView()
    let totalLabel = UILabel()
    var doneButton: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)

        var cfg = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
        cfg.title = "Done"
        doneButton = UIButton(configuration: cfg, primaryAction: UIAction() { _ in
            self.view.endEditing(true)
        })
        
        totalLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(totalLabel)
        
        doneButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(doneButton)
        
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            totalLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: doneButton.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            totalLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            totalLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: doneButton.heightAnchor),

            doneButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            doneButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: totalLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            doneButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),

            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: doneButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
        ])
        
        totalLabel.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        totalLabel.textColor = .white
        
        tableView.register(CompetitorCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CompetitorCell.identifier)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        // let's create some sample data
        materials = (0..<20).map {
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
            var m: Material = Material()
            m.name = formatter.string(for: $0)!
            m.quantity = 1
            return m
        }
        
        // handle keyboard covering cells...
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        
        // only show "Done" button if editing is active
        doneButton.isHidden = true
        
        // update the "Total" label
        updateTotal()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return materials.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CompetitorCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CompetitorCell
        
        // set the label and text field
        cell.label.text = "Material: " + materials[indexPath.row].name
        let q = materials[indexPath.row].quantity
        cell.quantityTextField.text = q > 0 ? "\(q)" : ""
        
        // set the "callback" closure
        cell.quantityEdited = { [weak self] theCell, theValue in
            
            // safely unwrap optionals
            guard let self = self else { return }
            guard let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: theCell) else { return }
            
            // update our data
            self.materials[indexPath.row].quantity = theValue
            
            // update "Total" label
            self.updateTotal()
            
        }
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func updateTotal() {
        let t = materials.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.quantity }
        totalLabel.text = "Total: \(t)"
    }
    
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        guard let keyboardFrame = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect else { return }
        
        // Get the size of the keyboard
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardFrame.height
        
        // Adjust the tableView's contentInset and scrollIndicatorInsets
        let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardHeight, right: 0)
        tableView.contentInset = contentInsets
        tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
        
        // Scroll to the active text field if it's hidden by the keyboard
        if let activeTextField = findActiveTextField(),
           let cell = activeTextField.superview?.superview as? UITableViewCell,
           let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
            tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .middle, animated: true)
        }
        
        self.doneButton.isHidden = false
    }
    
    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        // Reset the tableView's contentInset and scrollIndicatorInsets
        let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        tableView.contentInset = contentInsets
        tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

        self.doneButton.isHidden = true
    }
    
    func findActiveTextField() -> UITextField? {
        for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
            if let textField = cell.contentView.subviews.compactMap({ $0 as? UITextField }).first(where: { $0.isFirstResponder }) {
                return textField
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}


Looks like this when running:


You'll be able to edit the "quantity" in each cell ... it will update the data source ... and you can scroll up and down without the "ghost values" problem.

Very good, thorough answer with a nice clean solution. (Voted)

This worked, thanks for the answer
